# Converting a kotlin project from pom.xml to build.gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I am trying to convert my kotlin project from pom.xml to build.gradle with no success.
I have a working pom.xml and when i compile with "mvn compile" it works perfect and runs tests.
trying to build a new build.gradle to work with gradle with no success.
**pom.xml:**

```
    <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <avro.version>1.9.1</avro.version>
            <kotlin.version>1.3.61</kotlin.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${avro.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>schemas</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>schema</goal>
                                <goal>protocol</goal>
                                <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/</outputDirectory>
                                <stringType>String</stringType>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-compile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>testCompile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/test/java/org/mashov/generated/</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
                <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.61</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.microutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

**new build.gradle:**

```
import com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro.GenerateAvroJavaTask

group = 'com.mycompany.app'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin:0.17.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"
apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"

task generateAvro(type: GenerateAvroJavaTask) {
    source("src/test/java/avro/")
    outputDir = file("src/test/java/")
}

compileJava.source(generateAvro.outputs)

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // JAX-B dependencies for JDK 9+
    implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"

//    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M5'
    implementation 'com.github.dozermapper:dozer-core:6.5.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.61'
    //implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.61'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.61'
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.7'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25'
    testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.61'
    //testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    //testImplementation ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.0')
    //testImplementation ('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.2.4')
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly ('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0')

    test.useJUnitPlatform() // fix "test events not received" bug in IDEA

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? how can i build the project with running the tests with gradle?

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on links to 3rd party sites, like Github. You need to include all the relevant code here, in the question.

Comment: Sharone, you need to post what is the error you are getting on gradle build. Posting a new stackoverflow question with simplified project setup and the results you are seeing on different gradle build commands can help you get more answers. Like for e.g., does it fail in compiling stage, build artifacts or tests?

Answer (score 0):

1. navigate to pom file directory
2. run `gradle init` 
   This will convert the Maven build to a Gradle build, generating a `settings.gradle`
3. this message should appear: `Found a Maven build. Generate a Gradle build from this? (default: yes) [yes, no]`
4. press yes

**tasted on your pom file**

with

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-09-05 16:13:54 UTC
Revision:     55a5e53d855db8fc7b0e494412fc624051a8e781

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64
```

and

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T21:41:47+03:00)
Maven home: /Users/naortedgi/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Users/naortedgi/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.1-open
Default locale: en_IL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```